# How do I get current time in the format "2011-11-03 11:18:04" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format

I would like to have javascript return the current time in a format that looks like `"2011-11-03 11:18:04"`.

I tried `var XX = date()` but the returned format is not what I want. It looks like

> Tue Mar 15 2013 06:45:40 GMT-0500

How can I format time to look like `"2011-11-03 11:18:04"`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `date.getYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDay()` etc.

Comment: Why the -ve 2 points? Why isn't this a valid question for a newbie?

Comment: Because these kinds of questions have been answered many times. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I see. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) functions-

```
//MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss format
function formatDateTime(d){
  function addZeros(n){
     return n < 10 ? '0' + n : '' + n;
  }
  return addZeros(d.getFullYear()+1)+"-"+ addZeros(d.getMonth()) + "-" + d.getDate() + " " + 
           addZeros(d.getHours()) + ":" + addZeros(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + addZeros(d.getMinutes());
}
```

With [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)-

```
var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yS4da/579/)

Comment: I like this answer because using momentjs, the code looks most readable to newbies like me:)

Answer (score 5):

After creating the date correctly (`var xx = new Date();`, note the capital and the `new`), you have two choices:

1. Use the various methods of `Date` instances ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) | [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9)) and build the string yourself.
2. Use a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to do the work for you.

Comment: MomentJS looks like a good library for time formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function giveNewDate(){
var d = new Date();
var r = d.getFullYear()+"-"+zPlus(d.getMonth())+"-"+zPlus(d.getDate())+" "+zPlus(d.getHours())+":"+zPlus(d.getMinutes())+":"+zPlus(d.getSeconds());

function zPlus(digit){
    var digit = parseInt(digit);
    if (digit < 10){
    return "0"+digit;
    }else{
        return ""+digit;
    }
}
return r;
}

//to use: just call the giveNewDate() function
alert(giveNewDate());
</script>
```

In your script, simply call the giveNewDate() function where you need the text to appear.

Have a great day!

:)